# Excel generation, unreadable content

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I'm using `Apache POI 3.12` (`SXSSF` workbook) in order to generate `.xlsx` files. 
The problem is that I'm doing the generation and when I open the file I'm receiving an error message:

> Excel found unreadable content in file.xlsx. Do you want to recover
>   the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes.

After clicking `Yes`, the file opens and I'm receiving this notification

> Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this
>   workbook may have been repaired or discarded. Removed Records:
>   Comments from /xl/comments1.xml part (Comments) Repaired Records:
>   Comments from /xl/comments1.xml part (Comments)

After that, I unzip the excel file and check the `comments1.xml`. All my comments are present. All 216 of them.

The section of the code that generates the comments is the following

```
String comment = _propertiesHolder.getComment();
String commentAuthor = _propertiesHolder.getCommentAuthor();
if(comment != null)
{
    int colIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
    int rowIndex = cell.getRowIndex();
    CreationHelper helper = _workbook.getCreationHelper();
    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setCol1(colIndex);
    anchor.setCol2(colIndex + 1);
    anchor.setRow1(rowIndex);
    anchor.setRow2(rowIndex + 3);

    // Create the comment and set the text+author
    Comment cellComment = _drawingPatriarch.createCellComment(anchor);
    if(commentAuthor != null)
    {
        cellComment.setAuthor(commentAuthor);
        RichTextString rs = helper.createRichTextString(commentAuthor + ": " + comment);
        cellComment.setString(rs);
    }
    else 
    {
        cellComment.setString(helper.createRichTextString(comment));
    }

    cellComment.setRow(rowIndex);
    cellComment.setColumn(colIndex);

    // Assign the comment to the cell
    cell.setCellComment(cellComment);
}
```

Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this problem? Although no information was lost, clearly there is something wrong and I would like to fix it. The comments are retrieved from database (`varchar` datatype). The biggest comment is 138 characters long.

**Update**

Something that I forgot to mention. I've also run the same extraction using `hssf` implementation and no errors were present. It would be a safe assumption that the data are not the problem.

Comment: Are you doing that for a single comment, or are you adding multiple comments?

Comment: Multiple comments, 216 in total. One spreadsheet.

Comment: Why are you creating a new Drawing Patriarch each time then? As per [the warning in the javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createDrawingPatriarch%28%29), that's liable to remove any existing ones each time you call it!

Comment: I haven't seen that to be honest, but I've seen the implementation. It doesn't create if there is one already present `CTDrawing ctDrawing = getCTDrawing(); if (ctDrawing != null) { return getDrawingPatriarch(); }`

Comment: Although I will change it to use the same. It might be the case that I've missed something in the implementation

Comment: Ok, I've tried it. The problem remains.

Comment: Short term, your best bet would be to switch to using XSSFWorkbook, which does properly support Comments. Longer term, raise a bug in the [Apache POI bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI), including a junit unit test that shows the problem. And for bonus marks, add the SXSSFSheet support for it - the drawing will need to be created in the temp xml and written out, not just left in the parent XSSF sheet and then ignored

Comment: Unfortunately the xssf is very slow for my needs (big extraction, lot's of memory needed. gc hits repeatedly). Yes I will do the long term thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. It was with the author.

The problem is this line `cellComment.setAuthor(commentAuthor);`.

If for one comment we set

`cellComment.setAuthor("test")`

and then in another comment we set

`cellComment.setAuthor("test ")`

There will be an error shown when opening the file. Mind the whitespace. The solution is to trim the author string before setting it.